# make blue balls follow red balls without colliding with other blue balls in javascript game

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

so i am new to javascript and trying to make kinda like a game... in this game the red ball can move and the blue balls is supposed to follow the red balls like the blue balls should attaracts towards the red one

right now they are following but the blue balls overlaps each other and just turn in 1 ball at last...

i dont want this overlaping... how to that?

here's my code

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth-20;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-20;

let gameover = false;
let x = canvas.width / 2;
let y = canvas.height / 2;
let dx = 0;
let dy = 0;

x3=y3=0;
virx = new Array();
viry = new Array();

for (i=0; i<25; i++)
{
    virx.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerWidth-20) + 1));
    viry.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerHeight-20) + 1));
}

const state = {
  "ArrowRight": false,
  "ArrowLeft": false,
  "ArrowUp": false,
  "ArrowDown": false
}



function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();

  for (i=0; i<25; i++)
  {
    newpoint();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(virx[i], viry[i], 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fillStyle = "blue";
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
}

function logic() {

  const direction = determineDirection();

  if (direction.dx) {
    dx = dx + direction.dx;
  }

  if (direction.dy) {
    dy = dy + direction.dy;
  }

  x = x + dx;
  y = y + dy;

  if (dx > 0) {
    dx -= 0.02;
  }
  if (dx < 0) {
    dx += 0.02;
  }
  if (dy > 0) {
    dy -= 0.02;
  }
  if (dy < 0) {
    dy += 0.02;
  }

}

function play() {
  draw();
  logic();
}









document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function newpoint()
{
    flag=0;
    vx= x - virx[i];
    vy= y - viry[i];
    vsize = Math.sqrt((vx*vx) + (vy*vy));
    vn_x = vx / vsize;
    vn_y = vy / vsize;

    newx = virx[i] + 0.5 * vn_x;
    newy = viry[i] + 0.5 * vn_y;
    // virx[i] = newx;
    // viry[i] = newy;

    // for (j=0; j<25; j++)
    // {
        // c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((virx[j]-newx), 2)+Math.pow((viry[j]-newy), 2));

        // if (c<20)
        // {
            // flag=1;
        // }
    // }

    if (flag==0)
    {
        virx[i] = newx;
        viry[i] = newy;
    }
}

function determineDirection() {
  const {
    ArrowRight,
    ArrowLeft,
    ArrowUp,
    ArrowDown
  } = state
  if (ArrowRight && ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: .040,
      dy: -.040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowRight && ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: .040,
      dy: .040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft && ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: -.040,
      dy: -.040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft && ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: -.040,
      dy: .040
    };
  }
  if (ArrowLeft) {
    return {
      dx: -.040,
      dy: 0
    }
  }
  if (ArrowRight) {
    return {
      dx: .040,
      dy: 0
    }
  }
  if (ArrowUp) {
    return {
      dx: 0,
      dy: -.040
    }
  }
  if (ArrowDown) {
    return {
      dx: 0,
      dy: .040
    }
  }
  return {
    dx: 0,
    dy: 0
  }
}

function keyDownHandler({
  key
}) {
  state[key] = true;
}

function keyUpHandler({
  key
}) {
  state[key] = false;
}
setInterval(play, 10);
```

Comment: How is your question related to Python or C++?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen actually its a math question... so any coder could handle... that was my thought... but i still removed the tags.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

In any moment of the game you know positions of both red and blue balls. Let's call "vector" the increments of `x` and `y` between balls.

```
vx= red_x - blue_x
vy= red_y - blue_y
```

In order to use some force-magnitude `f` it's better to work with a vector of size 1:

```
vsize = sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)
vn_x = vx / vsize
vn_y = vy / vsize
```

Now the blue ball must be moved toward the red ball:

```
newblue_x = blue_x + f * vn_x
newblue_y = blue_y + f * vn_y
```

Comment: that totally worked... but it has a little bug ... all the blue atlast turn into one by keep following the red one... can you make it like so the blue balls dont overlap?

Comment: @fgh The "don't overlap" deserves its own question. Essentially, when two balls meet the sum of both radious is the same as the distance between their centers. Check this distance and take the decision you wish.

Comment: i tried it,  the commented area in code shows the distance part but i think making so many calculation in each 1/10 of the second just hang the game and nothing moves... can you please help solve that issue?